# Components renders under another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My Tag Component, which consist out of rendered texts and a text input component,  renders under another component, my button and behaves super weird.

If you look at the gif you can also see, that the tags from the second line onwards are not getting wrapped by my container style as well.

I made a gif, which should make it easier to see :)
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/JmD2VWAXU3S12LQ0Ya

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,

    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingLeft: 9,
    paddingRight: 9,
    height: 30,
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  tagContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  tags: {
    backgroundColor: "#9AA5B1",
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingLeft: 9,
    paddingRight: 9,
    paddingTop: 4,
    paddingBottom: 4,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 4,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5F7FA',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingLeft: 9,
    paddingRight: 9,
    height: 30,
    marginRight: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});

renderTags1 = (tag, index, deleteTag) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={index => deleteTag(index)}
      style={styles.tags}
      key={`${tag}-${index}`}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{tag}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const InputTags = ({ tags, value, onChangeText, deleteTag }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tagContainer}>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => {
          return this.renderTags1(tag, index, deleteTag);
        })}
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholder="Outdoor"
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText({ text })}
        value={value}
        autoCorrect={false}
        multiline={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export { InputTags };
```

For my Button :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    backgroundColor: '#E12D39',
    width: 280,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  text: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Semibold',
    fontSize: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

const SearchButton = ({ onPress, text }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.view} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export { SearchButton };
```

Expected behavior is  for the Button to go down. Tried to remove every single flex property, but could not quite figure it out yet

Comment: where is the button? I don't see it in the code. Show us the styles and HTML for it.

Comment: The button seems to have some type of absolute styling on it. Also you should have the input tag just be on its own line (block-level element)

Comment: The problem seems to be in your button. It's affecting the layout. Is it absolute?

Comment: thanks for your help! Eric actually solved it, although i am not quite too sure how :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the height is not increasing when it wraps, could confirm it by making the container bg a different color

Looks like you hard coded the height to be 30, which is probably causing the bug

Comment: Eric, it actually solved all the problems! I get why it solved the problem with the wrapping not extending (stupid me :P ) but the whole rendering under the Button thing? Do you have any idea how these things belong together?